# Create a virtual environment with upgraded site packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, distribute

I am trying to create a virtual environment with distribute version==0.6.35, everytime I create it, I get following site packages after activating it

```
distribute==0.6.26
mercurial==2.2.2
virtualenv==1.7.1.2
virtualenvwrapper==3.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

1. I want to know, on which basis Virtual environment is installing
   these site packages with particular version ?
2. How can I create a virtual environment with distribute==0.6.35 ?

**What I have tried.**
I have tried to upgrade the distribute version to 0.6.35, not working.

```
pip install distribute --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking distribute from http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz#md5=e55298c7e3a233df1a47a4881a0c9800
  Using download cache from /Users/nileshsharma/.pip/cache/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fd%2Fdistribute%2Fdistribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute

Installing collected packages: distribute
  Found existing installation: distribute 0.6.26
    Not uninstalling distribute at /Users/nileshsharma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.26-py2.7.egg, outside environment /Users/nilesh/env/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nilesh/bin/..
```

Even I have tried to uninstall this distribute version, not working.

```
pip uninstall distribute
Not uninstalling distribute at /Users/nileshsharma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.26-py2.7.egg, outside environment /Users/nileshsharma/Sites/env/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nilesh/bin/..
```

Comment: `virtualenv` depends on either `distribute` or `setuptools`, and I believe it prevents you from erasing or replacing whichever one a given environment is depending on. It _may_ just be a matter of creating an environment without a copy of `distribute`, so you can install one from inside.

Comment: Meanwhile: which versions of `virtualenv` and `python` do you have, and what command lines did you use for creating and activating the environment, and what env variables and config file entries do you have? (If you can show the output from the commands too, that would also be very helpful.)

Comment: You are using `--no-site-packages` when creating the venv, right?

Comment: … or at least not using `--system-site-packages`.

Comment: yeah I tried using --no-site-packages, got the message that this option has got depreciated.Can't use anymore

Comment: virtualenv==1.7.1.2, Python==2.7.1

Comment: creating command - virtualenv ENV --no-site-packages, activating command - source ENV/bin/activate